# How to plus all the values of a same index in JS array with VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have some products that I have created an array for showing them with VueJS & every product that user chooses goes to a list and every time that clicks on the products, It will increment the "Count" value. Every "Count" value times to the "Price" & writes "Total Price", But this "TotalPrice" is for just a product. So my question is that how can I plus all "TotalPrice" from all products to show the user Total Price ?
I should o that with "For Loop" ?

```
Persons: [
    {Name: 'Ali', Family: 'Bahaari', Age: 20, Count: 0, Price: 200},
    {Name: 'Akbar', Family: 'Jahan', Age: 30, Count: 0, Price: 2500},
    {Name: 'Amir', Family: 'Pirozi', Age: 40, Count: 0, Price: 500},
    {Name: 'Reza', Family: 'Khosravi', Age: 50, Count: 0, Price: 100}
]

<tr v-for="Active in Activated">
    <td>{{ Active.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ Active.Family }}</td>
    <td>{{ Active.Age }}</td>
    <td>{{ Active.Count }}</td>
    <td>{{ Active.Price }}</td>
    <td>{{ Active.Count * Active.Price }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a `computed` property and count total sum in it:

```
computed : {
    totalPrice(){ return this.Activated.reduce((accumulator,currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue.Count * currentValue.Price)
}
```

Then use it in template like any other variable: `{{ totalPrice }}`

Comment: **computed** property, to be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example

http://jsbin.com/xumugemiza/edit?html,js,output

```
const app = new Vue({

  el: '#app',

  data: {
    persons: [
    {Name: 'Ali', Family: 'Bahaari', Age: 20, Count: 0, price: 200},
    {Name: 'Akbar', Family: 'Jahan', Age: 30, Count: 0, price: 2500},
    {Name: 'Amir', Family: 'Pirozi', Age: 40, Count: 0, price: 500},
    {Name: 'Reza', Family: 'Khosravi', Age: 50, Count: 0, price: 100}
    ]
  },

  computed: {
     total() {
       let total = 0
       this.persons.forEach(person => total += person.price )
       return total
     }
  }

})
```

Comment: Why `filter`? Why not `forEach`?

Comment: No special reason, will edit it.In case of performances forEach should be faster than filter ?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe it's faster. Maybe the engine can detect that the returned value is discarded so just runs foreach instead.

Comment: As I know the normal `for` loop is faster than this "functional" methods - map, reduce, filter, forEach etc.But not sure too, if there is any difference between forEach and filter in performance case

Comment: That really doesn't make any significant difference, use the one you like :) for..of might be preferred when the collection is not an array but an iterable interface. Otherwise use the one that looks better in code.